# Ajax Catalog Events only working when Inspect Element Open

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have had https://github.com/czone-tech/magento2-ajaxified-catalog installed within a Magneto 2 store and its worked perfect for ages however suddenly stopped.

Strangely it works if i open inspect element. There are no errors shown in console and am unsure what would be the difference or cause different based on inspect element.

This is occurring if you navigate to a category like http://staging.buzzcateringsupplies.com/bar-supplies/bar-utensils/cocktail-utensils.html and select a filter on the side the page reloads. Try the same with inspect element open and the expected ajax behavior occurs. Is there anything anyone can suggest that would cause this?

Comment: for me it works absolutely the same with inspector closed and opened

Comment: For me it takes a few clicks sometimes to start working. For you is it reloading the page?

Comment: when i select a filter, a loadin icon appears and then the new results populate in, does not look like a page reload

Comment: Yeah thats it working. it often reloads the page for me however. Maybe something breaking occasionaly

Comment: saw the same behaviour now, looks like it doesnt override the anchor click behaviour at some time, e.g the script that catches click and parses data-action attribute doesnt run

Comment: Oh i think ive fixed it now. Just paniced for a min as need to lauch this soon was a bit baffed. Still am at how it works sometimes and not others but seems to work every time now on dev version of site.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look for me however!

Comment: for me it worked when inspector is open and the full-reload behaviour occurs i write this `jQuery(".item a").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();return false; })` into console and ajax loading works

Comment: Yeah that fixes it also . Cheers dude